# I have 5 time series in a graph, I want to hide the labels of 3 of them, how can I do this?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

This means that while the labels of 2 are shown, the labels of 3 are not. How can I 'hide' labels?

---

**UPDATE:** To clarify - how do I make the legend automatically disappear when it's a blank series, and appear otherwise?

Comment: Do you mean you want to edit the legend? If you can, please put a screen shot so we can see what you mean?

Comment: oops yes - i mean hide the legends for some of them

Comment: why the downvote?? - i want to have a variable number of time series in my graph, so some are blank series some of the time -that's why i asked this question

Comment: -1, please edit your question to include all of the detail and revisions in your comments.  Also, please provide some example of what you have or are trying to get, right now this is an erractically moving target.  Case in point, both answers given so far (mine included) are to completely different questions (or interpretations of them).

Answer (score 0):

To add labels one series at a time, **don't use the Ribbon Data Labels button**.  Instead

1. Select a series you want the labels added to directly in your chart, then
2. Right click for your context menu, then
3. Choose `Add Data Labels`.
4. Repeat as necessary.

[image: Data Labels]

You can also choose only a single data point to label, if you don't want to label the entire series.

Answer (score 0):

Just single click on the legend text and delete it.

**Update** Based upon your new question, in your table try

[image]

As you can see, Cell A4 will display the series name (in this case Karl) providing all columns have data. The legend will still appear as a colour line, but no text will be associated (not sure if this is good enough).

Comment: Hmm ok upon second thoughts, how do I make the legend automatically disappear when it's a blank series, and appear otherwise?

Comment: Use an IF statement in the field. So, if your row 2 had values, row 3 had values but row 4 didn't (where A2, A3 and A4 are the titles (series)) then do an if statement to check if any value is present and either display nothing or the series

Comment: how do i use an IF statement in the legend?